Azure Container App - how to safely/conveniently access apps across different environements/VNETs?
New to Azure networking - I have set up 2 Azure Container apps (A and B) in different resource groups/VNETs. I want to access B from A, ideally via VNET/subnet peering, and ideally (?) via a static custom name.
Current approach for reachability:
After pairing the nets, I have set up a private DNS zone using B's FQDN (dynamically provisioned via terraform to be the one of the latest revision) in a CNAME record.
When I try to access one container app from the other using its FQDN, it works fine. When I do nslookup myAppA.internal (as per the CNAME record I created) it resolves to the correct FQDN and the container app's environment IP. Thus, a curl to the CNAME record will fail, even if the FQDN is correct (This Container App is stopped or does not exist.). Sample code:
resource "azurerm_subnet" "containerEnv" {
  name                 = "${var.name}-containerEnv"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.2.0/23"]
  service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "${var.name}-vnet"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "main" {
  name                       = var.name
  location                   = var.location
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.main.id
  infrastructure_subnet_id   = azurerm_subnet.containerEnv.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "main" {
  name                = "${var.name}.internal"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.name}-link"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.main.name
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.main.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "networkB" {
  for_each = var.remote_virtual_network_ids

  name                  = "${var.name}-B-link"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.main.name
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_id    = each.value
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_cname_record" "appA" {
  name                = local.name
  record              = azurerm_container_app.main.latest_revision_fqdn
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  ttl                 = 300
  zone_name           = var.dns_zone_name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "B" {
  for_each = var.remote_virtual_network_ids

  name                      = "peer-to-remote-B"
  remote_virtual_network_id = each.value
  resource_group_name       = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name

  # TODO Seems to have implications public DNS entries, shelved for now.
  # peer_complete_virtual_networks_enabled = false
  # local_subnet_names = [azurerm_subnet.containerEnv.name]
  # remote_subnet_names                    = var.remote_subnet_names

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [azurerm_virtual_network.main]
  }
}

Currently the access is granted via IP whitelisting of A's outbound environment IP within apps B's ingress settings. This is also not ideal as as per Azure documentation, this IP might change. Using the subnet's connected subnets access space won't work though. How can I safely communicate between the subnets/vnets apps without using non-static IP address whitelisting? Sample code:

resource "azurerm_container_app" "A" {
  name                         = local.name
  container_app_environment_id = var.container_app_environment_id
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
  revision_mode                = "Single"
  (...)

  ingress {
    external_enabled           = true
    allow_insecure_connections = false
    target_port                = 1234

    traffic_weight {
      percentage      = 100
      latest_revision = true
    }

    dynamic "ip_security_restriction" {
      for_each = var.allowed_ip_ranges
      content {
        ip_address_range = ip_security_restriction.value
        action           = "Allow"
        name             = "A"
      }
    }

  }

  template {
    min_replicas = 1
    max_replicas = 1

    container {
      name   = local.A
      image  = "registry"
      cpu    = "0.5"
      memory = "1Gi"

    }
  }
}

General question:
Overall, what's an ideal setup to be able to securely access app B from app A and vice versa using automated provisioning (I'm using terraform), ideally in an easy-to-understand manner?

Have you tried any code so far @honest_annie

Yes, added some sample code.


Accessing apps over environments and vnets.

Here is an approach for setting up secure communication between Azure Container Apps A and B across different environments and VNETs
The following setup ensure the connection between the vnets and allows communciations using FQDNs without dynamic IPs which is mentioned in your approach.
My configuration:
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peer_a_to_b" {
  name                      = "peer-a-to-b"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.name
  virtual_network_name       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_a.name
  remote_virtual_network_id  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_b.id
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peer_b_to_a" {
  name                      = "peer-b-to-a"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_b.name
  virtual_network_name       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_b.name
  remote_virtual_network_id  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_a.id
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_analytics" {
  name                = "log-analytics-demo"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.location
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "env_a" {
  name                       = "container-env-a"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.name
  infrastructure_subnet_id   = azurerm_subnet.subnet_a.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.id
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "env_b" {
  name                       = "container-env-b"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_b.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_b.name
  infrastructure_subnet_id   = azurerm_subnet.subnet_b.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.id
}

resource "azurerm_container_app" "app_a" {
  name                         = "container-app-a"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.name
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.env_a.id
  revision_mode                = "Single"

  ingress {
    external_enabled           = false
    target_port                = 80
    allow_insecure_connections = false

    traffic_weight {
      percentage      = 100
      latest_revision = true
    }
  }

  template {
    container {
      name   = "appvksba"    # Updated to comply with naming restrictions
      image  = "${azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}/mycontainer:latest"
      cpu    = 0.25
      memory = "0.5Gi"
    }
  }

  depends_on = [ azurerm_private_dns_zone.dns_zone ]
}

resource "azurerm_container_app" "app_b" {
  name                         = "container-app-b"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_b.name
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.env_b.id
  revision_mode                = "Single"

  ingress {
    external_enabled           = false
    target_port                = 80
    allow_insecure_connections = false

    traffic_weight {
      percentage      = 100
      latest_revision = true
    }
  }

  template {
    container {
      name   = "appvksbb"   
      image  = "${azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}/mycontainer:latest"
      cpu    = 0.25
      memory = "0.5Gi"
    }
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_private_dns_zone.dns_zone ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dns_zone" {
  name                = "privatelink.internal"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "vnet_a_link" {
  name                  = "vnet-a-link"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dns_zone.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_a.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "vnet_b_link" {
  name                  = "vnet-b-link"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dns_zone.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_b.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_cname_record" "app_b_cname" {
  name                = "appvksbb"
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dns_zone.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_app_a.name
  record              = azurerm_container_app.app_b.latest_revision_fqdn
  ttl                 = 300
}




this much better approach as this using VNET peering and private DNS ensures stable internal routing wthout relying on dynamic IPs.
Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network_peering
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=workload-profiles-env%2Cazure-cli

Thank you, but with azurerm_container_app.ingress.external_enabled  = false within the container app, the access is limited to the container app environment - no? Think I found the missing piece to my understanding, however. In azurerm_container_app_environmentthere is a setting for internal_load_balancer_enabled = true, which then scopes ingress to VNET when ingress is enabled in the container app. This is then also reflected in the portal UI. Documentation on Azure side is imho rather misleading/incoherent here - if I understand it correctly now.

Yes, youre right setting external_enabled = false limits access to the container app environment, making it accessible only within the VNET. Enabling internal_load_balancer_enabled = true in the azurerm_container_app_environment ensures that the app's ingress is scoped to the VNET, allowing secure internal communication as intended. hoping this solution helps you @honest_annie
